# Combining four shaded relief images into one single image using GIS overlay technique?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, hillshade

I have prepared four shaded relief images (hillshade) with four contrasting illumination directions 0°, 45°, 90° and 135°.

I would like to combine four shaded relief images to produce one shaded relief image with multi - illumination directions (0°,45°,90°,and 135°) for lineament analysis.

How could I combine these four shaded relief images using GIS overlay technique in ArcMap 10.1?

Answer (score 2):

I used the following algorithm to calculate many shaded reliefs (SRTM, ASTER) with different illumination directions. It is AML code, but it should be no problem to identify the corresponding Spatial Analyst functions and raster calculator expressions.

```
shade225 = hillshade(dgm, 225, 65, shade, 15)
shade270 = hillshade(dgm, 270, 65, shade, 15)
shade315 = hillshade(dgm, 315, 65, shade, 15)
shade360 = hillshade(dgm, 360, 65, shade, 15)
smo = focalmean(dgm)
asp = aspect(smo)
asp1 = con(isnull(asp), 293, asp)
w225 = sqr(sin((asp1 - 225) div 57.296))
w270 = sqr(sin((asp1 - 270) div 57.296))
w315 = sqr(sin((asp1 - 315) div 57.296))
w360 = sqr(sin(asp1 div 57.296))
temp = w225 * shade225 + w270 * shade270 + w315 * shade315 + w360 * shade360
hillshade_image = int(temp div 2)
```

The resulting hillshade_image looks like this:

[image]